# How do "entrenched" and "their regimes in tighter control over their peoples" work in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Both Kim Il Sung and Syngman Rhee ended the war firmly entrenched in power and their regimes in tighter control over their peoples

This  is snippet from [Korea: A Very Short Introduction](https://academic.oup.com/book/28408/chapter/228829628) (online at [google books](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Korea_a_Very_Short_Introduction/OvDGDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Syngman%20Rhee%20ended%20the%20war%20firmly%20entrenched%20in%20power%22&pg=PA85&printsec=frontcover))

I don't understand how "entrenched" and "their regimes in tighter control over their peoples" works in this sentence. Can you help me parse this sentence?

Comment: I think it is missing a 'with' after 'and' and before 'their regimes'.

Comment: Can you identify the source of this quote please?

Comment: This appears to be https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Korea_a_Very_Short_Introduction/OvDGDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Syngman+Rhee+ended+the+war+firmly+entrenched+in+power%22&pg=PA85&printsec=frontcover

Comment: this snippet from Korea: A Very Short Introduction(https://academic.oup.com/book/28408/chapter/228829628)

Answer (score 0):

"Entrenched in power" is a passive participle clause that complements the main clause and describes the state of the two men at the end of the war.

The second phrase is coordinated with "and" and seems intended to be an independent clause. The subject of this clause is "their regimes", however that "clause" is deficient, it is missing the verb, which you are supposed to insert by parallelism with the first clause: "Their regimes ended the war in tighter control over their peoples".

That interpretation seems the best we can do with this rather ill-written sentence.

Comment: thank your answer,I want to ask you that  "Both Kim Il Sung and Syngman Rhee ended the war firmly entrenched in power " can be interpreted as "the two men were entrenched in power when they end the war"?

Comment: Yes, or perhaps "were entrenched when the war ended"  (although written as an active sentence, the meaning of "end" is generous enough to mean that the subject didn't cause the war to end as an actor)